# Supporting 9.6 inch and 10.1 inch android tablet

Tags: android

I have to support android devices with screen resolution 1280*800(in dp)(KitKat) and 1280 * 752(dp)(Lollipop). The first one is a 10.1 inch tablet and second one is 9.6 inch tablet.

I am using same layout for all device and using externalized dimension to adjust layout for different screen.

But I am not able to separate the device using "values-sw720dp" and "values-sw800dp". If I use sw800dp both of them use the dimen value from sw800dp dimen folder.

How can I give separate dimension for the two devices?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @KushPatel Why is the device with smallest width of 752dp taking dimen values from values-sw800dp folder?

Answer (score 0):

Get your device's screnn inches programmatically and appy dimension

```
public static double getDeviceInches(Activity activity) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getMetrics(activity);
    int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
    int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;

    float widthDpi = metrics.xdpi;
    float heightDpi = metrics.ydpi;

    float widthInches = widthPixels / widthDpi;
    float heightInches = heightPixels / heightDpi;

    return getDiagonalInches(widthInches, heightInches);
}

private static double getDiagonalInches(float widthInches, float heightInches) {
     double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt((widthInches * widthInches) + (heightInches * heightInches));
     float roundedValue = (float) Math.round(diagonalInches);
     return (double)roundedValue;
}

//From this, we can get the information required to size the display:
private static DisplayMetrics getMetrics(Activity activity) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics;
}

public static int convertDpToPx(Context context, int value) {
    // Get the screen's density scale
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale(0.5f is for rounding up value) (arrowWidth is 50dp)
    int pxValue= (int) (value * scale + 0.5f);
    return pxValue;
}
```

Put your above code in utility class and call getDeviceInches method from your acitivty or fragment class